# Task.WhenAll have finished BEFORE the Tasks it contains were finished

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

```
for (int i = 1; i < servers.Count;i++){
    var server = new SpeedTestServer(servers[i]);
    server.dist = haversine(server);

    if (closestKnownServer.dist - server.dist > distTreshold){
        closestKnownServer = server;
        this.servers.Add(server);
        this.servers.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    else if (Math.Abs(closestKnownServer.dist - server.dist) <= distTreshold){
        this.servers.Add(server);
        //BUG: we need to enable it but it causes hang
        pingTasks.Add(
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
                await server.ping();
                if (closestKnownServer.latency > server.latency){
                    closestKnownServer = server;
                    this.servers.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            })
        );
    }

}
await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
return closestKnownServer;
```

Look at the code above.
We create a List of Tasks and populate it.
Then we wait for them all.
BUT IT DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY!
The task which is generated with WhenAll if finished, but the Tasks it contains are not.
This can be visible if you place breakpoints into the lambda and into the last line of the method.

[The full code](https://github.com/KOLANICH/CSharp-SpeedTest-Client/blob/master/SpeedTest/SpeedTest.cs#L123-L139)

P.S. I know I'll also need a syncronization, but havent found a built-in library for it in c#.

Comment: The fact that you're using `List<T>.RemoveAt` from multiple threads suggests you have a problem to start with - until you've fixed that, I suspect any diagnostics you've got may well be incorrect. Are you able to show diagnostics *without* using the debugger, by the way?

Comment: hmm, what diagnostic do you speak about?

Comment: I'm talking about how you know that the waiting task has completed before all the individual tasks have - what have you done to indicate that without just hitting a breakpoint?

Comment: The way you're changing the list within the loop makes it very difficult to follow what you're trying to achieve, to be honest - and I wouldn't be surprised if that were responsible for the problem. I think it's more likely that your code is broken than that `WhenAll` is broken. Can you demonstrate `WhenAll` being broken in a short but complete program which *doesn't* do this sort of thread-unsafe list changing?

Comment: the result of the tasks is a server with least latency, but I got the server with very large latency ([largest long ever possible](https://github.com/KOLANICH/CSharp-SpeedTest-Client/blob/master/SpeedTest/SpeedTestServer.cs#L74), you can change the number in that line and see it in the window).

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>`. That's your problem right there. `StartNew()` doesn't support `async`, you should use `Task.Run()` instead. (Of course, this won't make the bug Jon mentioned go away, you need to fix that too.)

Comment: Big thanks. Now it works. Gone to fix syncronisation and read about the difference between StartNew and Run.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by Svick, `Task.Factory.StartNew` has different overloads and functionality to that of `Task.Run` these differences have been blogged about here: [`Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). The result of `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => ...` is a `Task<Task>`, so when calling `Task.WhenAll` you are only waiting for the outer `Task` to complete.

At the end of the blog post linked above, the differences as far as async and await are concerned are highlighted. You are left with three solutions for your problem:

Use `Task.Run` which has implicit async support, so will return a `Task` for the execution of an async delegate.

```
pingTasks.Add(
    Task.Run(async () => {
        await server.ping();
        if (closestKnownServer.latency > server.latency){
            closestKnownServer = server;
            this.servers.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    })
);
```

Use the `Unwrap(Task<Task>)` extension method which will turn a `Task<Task>` into a `Task`, it is designed exactly for this purpose when using the more advanced overloads of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

```
pingTasks.Add(
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await server.ping();
        if (closestKnownServer.latency > server.latency){
            closestKnownServer = server;
            this.servers.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }).Unwrap()
);
```

Await the result of `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => ...)` which will wait for the outer task complete, and result in a `Task` which is for the execution of the asynchronous delegate.

```
pingTasks.Add(
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await server.ping();
        if (closestKnownServer.latency > server.latency){
            closestKnownServer = server;
            this.servers.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    })
);
```

Out of all of these, for your situation, I would advise the use of `Task.Run` due to its implicit async support.